# ¿Cómo evito que me pase esto en la tabla html?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Tengo una tabla donde me muestra los datos de un usuario pero la columna del correo choca con la de categoría ¿Cómo puedo hacer que se ajuste la tabla? [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Acá les dejo el código html de la tabla, está dentro de un form pero no creo que tenga tanta relevancia. Lo que me interesa saber es como evito eso feo de arriba, si hay solución con css, con bootstrap, etc. Gracias

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" >
            <thead class="thead-dark" >
                <tr>       
                    <th>cedula</th>
                    <th>Nombre</th>
                    <th>apellido</th>
                    <th>Fecha Del Aporte</th>
                    <th>Aporte Asociado</th>
                    <th>Fecha Aporte del Asociado</th>
                    <th>Aporte Patrono</th>
                    <th>Fecha Aporte del Patrono</th>
                    <th>Monto total</th>
                    <th>Estado</th>

                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td> <?php echo $cedula ?> </td>
                    <td> <?php echo $nombre ?> </td>
                    <td> <?php echo $apellido ?> </td>
                    <td><input type="date" class="form-control" name="fechaAporte" placeholder="Fecha del Aporte" value="<?php echo $fechaAporte; ?>"></td>
                    <td><input type="number" class="form-control" name="aporteAsociado" placeholder="Fecha del Pago" value="<?php echo $aporteAsociado; ?>"></td>
                    <td><input type="date" class="form-control" name="fechaPagoAsociado" placeholder="Monto del Aporte" value="<?php echo $fechaPagoAsociado; ?>"></td>
                    <td><input type="number" class="form-control" name="aportePatrono" placeholder="Tipo de Aporte" value="<?php echo $aportePatrono; ?>"></td>
                    <td><input type="date" class="form-control" name="fechaAportePatrono" placeholder="Estado del aporte" value="<?php echo $fechaAportePatrono; ?>"></td>
                    <td><input type="number" class="form-control" name="montoAporte" placeholder="Estado del aporte" value="<?php echo $montoAporte; ?>"></td>
                    <td><input type="number" class="form-control" name="estado" placeholder="Estado del aporte" value="<?php echo $estado; ?>"></td>


                <tr>

            </tbody>
        </table>
        <br>


        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="btnGuardar">Guardar Cambios</button>
```

Comment: Me parece que ese código no genera esa tabla

Comment: Cierto, no me di cuenta xD

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Como ya han dicho, un texto como `estecorreoesmuylargo@gmail.com` siempre se sobrepasará si su contenedor no es flexible o no tiene el ancho suficiente.

En cada celda puedes usar:

```
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
```

De esa manera, el texto no sobrepasará su contenedor, y además, se le agregarán 3 puntos al final, y quedaría así `estecorreoesmuy...`.

Por otro lado, si lo que quieres es mostrar siempre el correo completo, podrías insertar la etiqueta `<wbr>`. Más información [aquí](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/wbr)
Esta etiqueta creará saltos de líneas cuando se de la oportunidad, en la posición que lo pongas. Ejemplo: `estecorreoesmuylargo<wbr>@gmail.com`. Deberás probar de todas maneras como funciona.

Answer (score 2):

Una dirección de correo como: `juancabello@gmail.com` se considera como una sola palabra, y ocupará ese ancho automático, sin saltos de línea.

Te sugiero que solo muestres parte de la dirección de correo en la tabla (Ej.: los 10 primeros caracteres), y uses el atributo `title` para mostrar la dirección completa cuando se sobrepongan el cursor.

```
<td title="<?php echo $email; ?>"> 
    <?php echo strlen($email) > 10 ? substr($email, 0, 10) . '...' : $email; ?> 
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

ponle un style a cada `<td>` : `overflow: hidden`

Evitaras que se monte el texto.